# Why I am not able to edit any post?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, editing

Whenever I try to edit any question or any tag below message is shown to me.

> This post has been deleted - no more edits are allowed

Can any one tell why I am not able to edit anything, While I edit many tags successfully.

For example I want to edit [Why does the Rig Veda call Vishnu a mountain-roaming bull?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3432/why-does-the-rig-veda-call-vishnu-a-mountain-roaming-bull).

> [image]

Comment: Can you post a link of the post you are trying to edit?

Comment: @Mr.Alien : Question is updated. Please check

Comment: Try to clear cookies/cache of your browser, log in back and try to edit the post, if still the issue persist, post a screenshot and if possible, post the header information(if you are a techie)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the screen, will report the devs

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Alien

Comment: That looks like a browser is displaying an AJAX response instead of making the call properly via JavaScript. What browser, operating system (and versions of both, if possible) are you using? What add-ons/extensions/plugins? Does this happen if you disable all add-ons/extensions/plugins?

Comment: I tried editing with firefox 32.0.3 , chrome latest with window 7 professional as an operating system.

Comment: Any extensions? What happens if you disable all extensions/add-ons?

Comment: Same issue I am getting even after disable all the extension.

Comment: Are you seeing any JavaScript errors in the console?

Comment: "NetworkError: 503 Service Unavailable - http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/posts/2574/edit"

Comment: Well, that's the answer then. There is a problem with your network :( - you need to talk to your system administrators/ISP.

Comment: @Oded : I can not edit anything by my account by my office n/w or by my home n/w even I when am connect to VPN. So is it really a network issue?

Comment: Could very well be. Clear out your cache - could be some old JavaScript got cached. Could be that there are some bad proxy servers between SE and you. Difficult to tell.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18214/discussion-between-urfusion-and-oded).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your account was blocked from suggesting edits due to too many rejected suggested edits within a short time period.

You seem to have made a very large amount of suggestions on tag wikis - a bunch of those got rejected, causing a temporary block.

The block should clear within a day or so.